# Show that the $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2^x+1}$

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions, symmetric-functions, even-and-odd-functions

I am struggling with this question. Seems simple enough right but NO.
I might be just overthinking it, but someone please help. To know if it is an odd function if $$f(-x)=-f(x).$$

Comment: Show function is odd

Comment: So what have you tried then?

Comment: maybe you typed f(x) wrong?

Comment: $f(x)=-1/2+1/(2^x+1)$ is odd.@yesman

Comment: If you ever want to check whether a function $f$ is odd, just see whether $f(-x)+f(x)$ simplifies to $0$. You clearly have a typo at the moment, as $f(0)\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

The Function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^x+1}$$
is **not odd**, you can check this by replacing $x$ by $-x$ and also by graph (it does not pass through origin, continuous at origin, $f(0)$ also defined).
$$f(-x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{-x}+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2^{x}}{2^{x}+1} \not=-f(x)$$
[image]

But if you have done a typo, which you probably have-
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^x+1}$$
Then this is a odd function, take LCM.
$$f(x)=\frac{1-2^x}{2(2^x+1)}$$ 
$$-f(x)=\frac{2^x-1}{2(2^x+1)}$$
$$f(-x)=\frac{1-2^{-x}}{2(2^{-x}+1)}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^x}}{2(\frac{1}{2^x}+1)}=\frac{2^x-1}{2(2^x+1)}=-f(x)$$
Also you can look at the graph.

[image]